# PI found in Minesweeper - a new conjecture

Tags: probability, pi, conjectures, monte-carlo

Playing with Monte Carlo simulations over Minesweeper, I happened by chance to find PI appearing in a pattern of the numbers relating to cells neighbouring mines on *n*n* grids with *n* mines.

My observations point to the following conjecture:

- We define $S_n$ as the average sum of all numbers on a quadratic Minesweeper board with dimensions $n\times n$, and a number of mines equal to $n$.
- We define $S_{n-1}$ as the average sum of all numbers on a quadratic Minesweeper board with dimensions $(n-1) \times (n-1)$, and a number of mines equal to $n-1$.
- Subtracting $S_{n-1}$ from $S_n$ yields approximately $7.85398 \approx 2.5\pi$.

The full conjecture is given in a PDF here: [Github link](https://github.com/henrik2706/MinesweeperConjecture/blob/main/minesweeper_conjecture.pdf)

I, being a mere computer scientist, do not have enough insight into the topic, so I have discussed this with a professor of mathematics at my university. He thinks the edge effects are not that important, and suggests looking closer at the overlaps, further suggesting looking at the Minesweeper grid as a torus.

What are your thoughts on this curious occurence of PI? Do you find any flaws in my conjecture?

Comment: Please put the essential information in the question itself, and not in an external resource.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, I will edit my question right away.

Comment: Had a read - what is sum, S, in your document?  The total number of mines around a cell?

Comment: $R=100$ repetitions is nothing. Come back when you've done $10,000$. (And yes, use a torus.)

Comment: @Chinny84 That should have been made clearer. The _S_ under the algebra section is the same as _avg_ in the pseudocode. It is the average sum of numbers on non-mine fields on a board with size n*n and n mines.

Comment: @TonyK Thanks for your input. I found it to converge rather quickly, and keep in mind that there's 100 iterations _for each_ board of size _n_, and thus there are 200*100 in total.

Comment: I’m not entirely sure (boundaries + mines can be adjacent), but I think that $\pi$ is coincidental… here, it can be the $8$ that matters, since every mine adds exactly $8$ points to the sum. The following is more a heuristic explanation than a rigorous proof. There are on average $\Theta(1)$ mines on the border, and $O(1)$ pairs of adjacent mines, so $nS_n=8n+O(1)$… so if $S_n-S_{n-1}$ has a limit, it should be $8$…

Comment: Your PDF is very hard to comprehend - it seems you often forget required parentheses (e.g. in the expression $(S_1-S_0)+\cdots +(S_n-S_{n-1})/N$); you didn't introduce $N$ in the first place (supposedly, $N=n$?); if you take $\lim_{N\to\infty}$, the result cannot again depend on $N$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen It's the computer scientist in me being sloppy with the notation, and the sudden inspiration leading me to scramble down a PDF in a matter of minutes. Will improve :)

Comment: @Mindlack I agree, it should. I am calculating the probabilities of mines being adjacent and thus lowering the sum of numbers now. Will see if I come up with something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make the back-of-the-envelope computation in *@Mindlack*'s comment exact:

With $n$ mines on an $n\times n$ board, the expected number of mines on an arbitrary field is exactly $\frac n{n^2}=\frac1n$. But if we know that a specific field is a mine, then for any *other* field, the expected number of mines on that field is $\frac{n-1}{n^2-1}=\frac1{n+1}$. Hence, if a field with $k$ neighbours is a mine, then the expected contribution to the sum by this mine is $k\cdot(1-\frac1{n+1})$ and therefore the expected contribution of that field (without already knowing that it is a mine) is
$$ \frac1n\cdot k\cdot\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)=\frac k{n+1}.$$
Now on our (non-toroidal) $n\times n$ board, we have $4$ corner fields with $3$ neighbours, $4n-8$ edge fields with $5$ neighbours, and $(n-2)^2$ inner fields with $8$ neighbours.
We conclude that
$$ S_n = 4\cdot \frac3{n+1}+(4n-8)\cdot\frac5{n+1}+(n-2)^2\frac8{n+1}=\frac{8n^2-12n+4}{n+1}=8n-20+\frac{24}{n+1}$$
exactly.

It follows that
$$ S_n-S_{n-1}=8-\frac{24}{n^2+n}$$
and
$$ \frac1nS_n=8-\frac{20}n+\frac{24}{n^2+n}.$$
It is no coincidence that the limit of these expressions as $n\to\infty$ is precisely $8$.

Comment: That settled it, thanks a bunch!